# Weblogic remote debugging using eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, weblogic, using

My Weblogic is installed in a Red hat OS machine.

In the startWebLogic.sh i have added this line
JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8888,server=y,suspend=n %JAVA_OPTIONS%"

When I try to connect from my Eclipse I get a 
"Failed to connect to remote VM. Connection refused.
Connection refused: connect"
message.

Can you please tell me where I may be going wrong?

Comment: Is your Eclipse and weblogic on different systems? If so, could port 8888 be blocked on Redhat OS?

Comment: Hi Raghuram. Thanks for you reply. Yes its in different systems. How do I check if its blocked and if blocked, how do i enable it

Comment: If you have `nmap` installed.  You can issue the command from your eclipse host: format: `nmap -p <port> <server>`, example: `nmap -p 8888 serverName.example.com`

Comment: you don't have to do anything additional (check your setDomainEnv.sh if it contains the line debugFlag="true". If so than you have weblogic setup for remote debugging).

Comment: @despot That comment is too simplistic.  There's more to it than that. A user should look through the rest of the script to see what port it's being set up for etc

Comment: @despot, thanks it worked by making that change. It takes the default port mentioned in setDomainEnv.sh/setDomainEnv.cmd (i.e 8453)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the **startWebLogic.sh** file in the **bin** folder, in the *RHEL* add this line

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8888,server=y,suspend=n
```

at the place where you find this string: `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java`.

Place the above line just after `${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java`

Comment: this will make no difference, since the way mujeeb did this is the preferred way. why are you anwsering your own question?

Comment: Well I found the answer after I posted the question. However the way I explain in my answer worked for me. However, thanks for your reply. Much appreciated.

Comment: This worked for me. Things were slightly different on Windows, but overall, the same process worked as expected.

Comment: @Salandur As a side note: it is [totally OK](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/17467/203290) and [even encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to answer own questions. This is even discussed in the Stack Overflow help center: [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 4):

I Know it may be late ... but I get errors like this, when I try to run eclipse debugging session while there is one session already running.

Answer (score 2):

Edit *<my_domain>/bin/setDomainEnv.sh* file and add this on top:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_OPTIONS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"
```

or
configure debug port

```
DEBUG_PORT=${DEBUG_PORT:=8000} 
JAVA_OPTIONS="$JAVA_OPTIONS -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=$DEBUG_PORT,server=y,suspend=n"
```

---

More info can be found here:
[How to setup remote debug with WebLogic Server and Eclipse](http://saltnlight5.blogspot.com.ee/2014/04/how-to-setup-remote-debug-with-weblogic.html)

Answer (score 0):

you can only connect to a running VM, so make sure your server is running.

if you are running on separate systems, it is possible and very likely that a firewall is blocking the connection. so contact your network administrator to see if this is true

Answer (score 0):

May be late but may help someone.

I use the eclipse plugin for weblogic 12c. 
I was trying to run the server in the debug mode by doing`righclick-->start in debug` and kept getting a "VM Connection refused" error. 
Then i did the following
1- I edited the startWeblogic.cmd to include

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8453,server=y,suspend=n
```

2- Rightclick on the PROJECT that i wanted to debug and went `MYproject-->Debug As-->**Debug On Server**` and it worked. Do not do `righclick-->start in debug` on the server, but do it on the specific project you want to debug.