# Connecting Eclipse to Weblogic server hosted on UNIX machine

Tags: eclipse, unix, weblogic

I have weblogic installed on a UNIX machine and my source code is in SVN.

I am trying to use the source code in Eclipse and want to know how I can integrate/connect the weblogic server hosted on UNIX machine so that I can develop/modify my application on Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using remote debugging. There is a question on StackOverflow about it here: [Weblogic remote debugging using eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882203/weblogic-remote-debugging-using-eclipse).

This is more detail from Oracle:

> In the startWebLogic.cmd script, specify the JAVA OPTIONS with:
>
> set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n
>
> The -XDebug parameter enables debugging. The -Xnoagent parameter disables the default sun.tools.debug debug agent. The -Xrunjdwp parameter loads the JPDA reference implementation of JDWP. Debugging is enabled on port 4000. The JDWP protocol is the protocol used to debug with a remote debugger.

Source: [Remote Debugging on WebLogic Server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/remotedebugwls-086628.html)

And how to set up the configuration in Eclipse:

> Next, configure a debug configuration for the Eclipse project. Select the Debug option in the Debug option list. The Debug frame gets displayed. In the Debug frame select the Remote Java Application node. Right-click on the node and select New. In the Debug configuration frame specify a name for the Debug configuration. Select the project that is to be debugged. Select the EclipseWebLogic project previously created in the Eclipse IDE. Select the default value for Connection Type. In the Connection Properties, specify localhost as the Host and specify the Port as the port that was specified in the startWebLogic batch script of the WebLogic server, [4000]. Click on the Apply button. A remote Java application debug configuration gets added.

Source: [Configuring Eclipse for Remote Debugging a WebLogic Java Application](http://eclipse.sys-con.com/node/169364)