# Eclipse configure Weblogic server installed on Virtual Box

Tags: eclipse, virtualbox, weblogic11g

I have installed **Weblogic Server** on Linux which is running on **Virtual Box**.

How can I integrate Weblogic server? How can I point to Weblogic Home on Linux when I configure server in Eclipse? Is the procedure same [as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10222022/connecting-eclipse-to-weblogic-server-hosted-on-unix-machine) **Remote Debugging With Eclipse**?

Any insight into this is highly appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to point to your WebLogic instance? A development enviroment? A client application?

Comment: @Viccari I would like to point to development environment which is installed on a virtual box and guest OS is Linux. Thanks

Comment: Ok, but what exactly are you trying to point to your dev environment? An Eclipse instance?

Comment: @Viccari Yes from Eclipse IDE, sorry I didn't mention that if that was your question. :-(