# Eclipse debugger hangs after upgrading from WebLogic 11g to WebLogic 12c

Tags: eclipse, debugging, weblogic, atg, oracle-commerce

We recently upgraded from WebLogic 11 to WebLogic 12c (v12.2.1.2) (We are running Oracle Commerce 11.3 framework using Java 8).  After the upgrade we found that the Eclipse debugger would hang indefinitely as you began to step through code and the only way to recover would be to suspend the debugger. We have tried multiple different versions of Eclipse including Mars, Neon, and Oxygen and they all demonstrated the same behaviour.   Below is the WebLogic JVM startup arguments we are using to enable debugging:

```
-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1044,server=y,suspend=n
```

In Eclipse we setup remote debugger and it would fire up correctly and my breakpoints would trigger correctly, however it would hang after stepping through a few lines of code (We tried debugging multiple different java classes)

Any thoughts on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the old JVM arguments no longer work with WebLogic 12c.  Using the below JVM arguments solved the issue:

```
 -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=1044,suspend=n
```

Comment: Not convinced. Running Weblogic 12.2.1.2 with Java 8 and the following 'debug' configuration `-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8187,server=y,suspend=n` so perhaps it is the `-Xnoagent`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26668723/remote-debugging-java-web-start-under-jvm-1-8 which appears to have a similar issue.  We did not upgrade the version of Java.

Comment: @radimpe See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882203/weblogic-remote-debugging-using-eclipse which includes -Xnoagent

Comment: Looking at the first site, I am setting my debug arguments via `Server Start` in the Weblogic Console (or manually editing the config.xml). Haven't had any issues. Are you setting yours via the .bat/.sh file? Either way, I now know what to change if I DO run into issues.

Comment: @radimpe setting them via .sh file

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue and used the following JVM args like @radimpe mentions:

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8543,server=y,suspend=‌​n -Xdebug
```

I dont think this is limited to WebLogic.